# Problemas plugin google no eclipse luna

Tags: aplicação-web, eclipse, plugin

Estou com algum problema com o plugin do google no eclipse Luna. Baixei todo o conteúdo certinho pelo instalador interno de sowtware do eclipse. Coloquei a url Google Update Site for Eclipse 4.4 - https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4 e baixei todo o conteúdo.
Acontece que quando clico em New Web application Project no plugin, nada acontece. Mesmo quando tento criar um Dynamic web Project, essa opção não aparece pra mim. Alguém sabe me dizer se está faltando alguma coisa? Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Parece que falta o *plugin* **WTP** (*Web Tools Platform*) no seu Eclipse. Se baixou a versão mais simples e "crua" que está disponível no site, não vai ter isso mesmo.

Baixe novamente o **Eclipse for JavaEE Developers**, pois essa versão vem com um conjunto completo de *plugins* para desenvolvimento.

Outra opção seria instalar diretamente do Update Site, mas em geral não compensa, porque o tempo de download e instalação vai ser bem maior.